# React Native Tabbar Android image not overflow

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

I'm using `react-native-router-flux`

The central button is higher than the Tabbar, on iOS works well but on Android the upper part of the button is cut, see the images:

iOS

[image]

Android

[image]

This is the style of the Tabbar Social component:

```
const BtnTabbarSocial = (props) => {
    const source = ...
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
                source={source} 
            />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = {
    container: {
        width: 64,
        height: 60,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 30,
        paddingBottom: 5,
        position: 'absolute',
    }
};
```